# What is the sum of subgradients of two functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Lets say I have  two functions, one is differentiable lets say $x^2$. Another is non differentiable |x|. What is the sum of the gradient of the two functions wrt x.

For $x^2$ it is 2x. For |x| it $\epsilon$ [-1 1]. So at x = 2. It is

$sign(grad(x^2))*,max((|grad(x^2)|-1),0)$ at x=2, is it?